# boost check_sanity() mutex lock

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I have 2 processes that use boost shared memory, running in a loop.

In every iteration the processes call `check_sanity()` before doing some stuff in the shared memory, I have a scenario where one of the processes crashes because of [alignment](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/boost-1.74.0/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/detail/mem_algo_common.hpp#L106) issue:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/detail/mem_algo_common.hpp:106: static void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::memory_algorithm_common<MemoryAlgorithm>::assert_alignment(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::memory_algorithm_common<MemoryAlgorithm>::size_type) [with MemoryAlgorithm = boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>; boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::memory_algorithm_common<MemoryAlgorithm>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion `uint_ptr % Alignment == 0' failed.
./start.sh: line 20:  3034 Aborted                 (core dumped)
```

After the crash, the second process stuck in the `check_sanity()` function, and when the first one is restarting he stuck there as well.

I looked at the boost source code and I saw that there is a `scoped lock mutex` in the `check_sanity()` function and there is an `assert` there so my guess is that the first process crash in the `assert` without unlocking the `scoped mutex`.

[boost](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/tree/boost-1.74.0) shared memory [check_sanity()](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/boost-1.74.0/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/rbtree_best_fit.hpp#L632) source code:

```
template<class MutexFamily, class VoidPointer, std::size_t MemAlignment>
bool rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidPointer, MemAlignment>::
    check_sanity()
{
   //-----------------------
   boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<mutex_type> guard(m_header);
   //-----------------------
   imultiset_iterator ib(m_header.m_imultiset.begin()), ie(m_header.m_imultiset.end());

   size_type free_memory = 0;

   //Iterate through all blocks obtaining their size
   for(; ib != ie; ++ib){
      free_memory += (size_type)ib->m_size*Alignment;
      algo_impl_t::assert_alignment(&*ib);
      if(!algo_impl_t::check_alignment(&*ib))
         return false;
   }

   //Check allocated bytes are less than size
   if(m_header.m_allocated > m_header.m_size){
      return false;
   }

   size_type block1_off  =
      priv_first_block_offset_from_this(this, m_header.m_extra_hdr_bytes);

   //Check free bytes are less than size
   if(free_memory > (m_header.m_size - block1_off)){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

For now, my solution when that's happening is to delete the shared memory and restart both of the processes so that the first one will create a new valid shared memory.

##Edit

> I'm using Boost version 1.74.

One process is a reader and the other is a writer:

```
typedef boost::circular_buffer<SharedPtr, ShmemAllocator> Container;

bip::managed_shared_memory segment;

Container* createContainer(bip::managed_shared_memory &segment) {
   bip::named_mutex container_lock{bip::open_or_create, SHM_MUTEX};
   if (std::unique_lock open_lk{container_lock, std::try_to_lock}) {
      segment = bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_or_create, SHM_NAME, SHM_SIZE);
      return segment.find_or_construct<Container>(CONTAINER)(CONTAINER_SIZE, segment.get_segment_manager());
   } else {
      throw boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception("cannot lock for creating container shared memory");
   }
}

Container* OpenContainer(bip::managed_shared_memory &segment) {
      bip::named_mutex container_lock{bip::open_only, SHM_MUTEX};
      if (std::unique_lock open_lk{container_lock, std::try_to_lock}) {
            segment = bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_only, SHM_NAME);
            auto container = segment.find<Container>(CONTAINER);
            return container.first;
      } else {
            throw boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception("cannot lock for creating container shared memory");
      }
}
```

The scenario is that the processes run in a loop, stop, restart and use the existing shared memory, sporadically after a few runs the alignment issue is happening and the processes get stuck.

I have two questions:

1. What could be the cause of the alignment issue?
2. Is there a better way to deal with locked `scoped mutex` to avoid blocked processes?

Comment: The best way seems to me is to finish "investigating the cause" of the actual crash that results in undefined behavior, and fix the real bug.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik, we investigate the issue of the corrupted memory for sure, this is our top priority, but my question is if the situation where there is an assertion in ```check_sanity()``` function Considered undefined behavior?

Comment: C++ is just too complicated. Noone who does not have the access to the full definition of these mysterious objects that are used in this function, like `m_header`, to be able to conclusively determine that. Not to mention everything else that's related to them...

Comment: Needs more code. Try to create a minimal self-contained example

Answer (score 0):

> After the crash the second process stuck in check_sanity() function and after the first one is restarting he stuck there as well.

This part is by design. Boost Interprocess has no portable implementation of robust mutexes (which is a hard problem).

The sketched work-around is common, or you can do it in software by using a timed try-lock to detect when the shared resource is stuck.

See also many other examples of this phenomenon: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20robust%20interprocess

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sehe. any ideas on the alignment issue? I don't understand why would the memory get out of alignment

Comment: That seems unrelated and is very likely caused by a form of [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere

Comment: The alignment issue causes the assertion that crashes the process with a locked mutex. Do you know what could cause this kind of behavior? why would the memory get out of alignment?